# PC shuts down while playing games (but not really?)

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, shutdown, temperature, game-controller

I recently started experiencing  occasional freezes in the games I play, lasting about 30 sec before the games return to their normal state, mainly while playing FIFA 17. And if that wasn't enough my PC shuts down after having FIFA 17 running for only a few minutes (which is weird considering i've been playing the game for 6 months without any issues). When the PC "shuts down" both of my monitor screens go black and the system seems to have turned off, however the fans and small lights placed on the side of the power-on button keep running.

My initial thoughts were that it was an overheating issue but after monitoring my temperatures several times while the "shutdown" was happening, I doubt it considering that they didn't look too bad:

---

**GPU =** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 - GDDR5 - 1024 MBytes

Max temperature: **67 °C**

---

**CPU =** AMD FX-6300 Six-Core (Vishera) - 3.50 GHz

Max temperature: **51 °C**

---

**HDD =** WDC WD10EZRX-00A8LB0 ATA Device

Max temperature: **33 °C**

---

**What I HAVE tried:**

- Disconnecting my Xbox 360 controller (+ uninstalling the drivers to it etc. as the issues began to occur short after I equipped myself with the controller)
- Disconnecting my second monitor
- Running the game in windowed mode as well as fidgeting with the settings like trying to lower the graphics etc.
- Updating all my drivers

Needless to say, none of the actions stated above have helped.

---

**Remaining specifications:**

**Operating system =** Windows 7 Home Premium - Service Pack 1

**Motherboard** = MSI 760GM-P21(FX) (MS-7641) 3.0

---

What else could be at fault? And why doesn't the PC turn off completely?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: maybe a setting in Power Options enabling the computer to go to sleep early?

Comment: Another possibility is a failing power supply.  It might be struggling to supply enough power during peak demand.

Comment: @SergioDominguez
It was set to go to sleep after 15 min. It might be that the PC isn't recognizing the game as activity for some reason, I'll post an update once I've tried playing after changing the setting from "15 min." to "Never".

Comment: @CharlesBurge That would be my last resort. I'll try what Sergio Dominguez suggested whereafter I'll try to install an older version of my graphics driver (after reading a little, it could very possibly be the culprit for whatever reason). It just feels weird cause wouldn't the power supply failing mean that the PC would turn off completely? Yet here it is, powering the fans and everything.

Comment: "...wouldn't the power supply failing mean that the PC would turn off completely?"  Not necessarily.  I've seen cases where they run OK under normal loads, but shut down when demand gets too high.  Or possibly just lose power on certain leads, such as the one powering the video card.  That might happen if solder leads are coming loose internally.  I agree it could be a last resort, but it's worth considering.

Comment: @CharlesBurge Absolutely, thanks for your input. I'll probably change it once I've figured it can't be a software problem anymore as none of the other components seem to be at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed the PSU, changed it and everything works well again. Towards the end the old PSU was failing so badly that I even got shutdowns while browsing the internet, after 1 day of testing with the new PSU, no shutdowns and freezes, so it seems like the PSU was the cause of both.

Comment: Good call for the PSU.  I've seen people replace everything else before finally deciding it "might" be the PSU.  Well, when it's the only thing that they hadn't changed and it's still having the same issue, yep!